# how to allow a dot '.' in a vue.js input fields

Tags: vue.js

Here I have written a code in vue.js. This code is for while user enters a number in a price field
then after three digit comma "," will prompt dynamically. SO this functionality is expected and it is working fine but the issue is while we try to enter a dot '.' manually it is not allowing us enter the dot. SO in this script i want to allow the user to enter a dot '.' manually. So please help me to solve this issue.

```
<div id="vue">
  <input type="text" v-model="price" />
</div>
```

```
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: {
    price: 0
  },
  watch: {
    price: function(newValue) {
      const result = newValue.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      Vue.nextTick(() => this.price = result);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing all non-digit characters so exclude `.` from that. You can use [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
newValue.replace(/[^.\d]/g, "")
```

Final code:

```
  watch: {
    price: function(newValue) {
      const result = newValue.replace(/[^.\d]/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      Vue.nextTick(() => this.price = result);
    }
  }
```

---

**UPDATE :** And in the other replace you have to exclude comma in decimal part for that you can use [negative look-behind assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
.replace(/\B(?<!\.\d+)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

Final code:

```
  watch: {
    price: function(newValue) {
      const result = newValue.replace(/[^.\d]/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?<!\.\d+)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      Vue.nextTick(() => this.price = result);
    }
  }
```